# How do I write a swagger endpoint using go-swagger where I can delay the consumption of the body in its parameters?

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-swagger

I need to define a swagger endpoint that needs to take in media types text and zip. Instead of having the generated package consume it and reassign it into separate types such as string, can I get the io.Readcloser passed through directly?

Answer (score 1):

Swagger spec:

```json
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "foo",
    "in": "body",
    "schema": {
      "type": string,
      "format": "binary"
    }
  }
]
```

Generated parameter:

```golang
type SomeParams struct {
    Foo io.ReadCloser
}
```

And in the generated `BindRequest` method, the request body ReadCloser is assigned to the `Foo` field:

```golang
    if runtime.HasBody(r) {
        o.Foo = r.Body
    }
```